# How to decode string representative of utf-8 with python?

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, encode

I have a **unicode** like this:

```
\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE4\xB8\x9C \xE6\x97\xA5\xE7\x85\xA7
```

And I know it is the string representative of `bytes` which is encoded with `utf-8`

Note that the string `\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE4\xB8\x9C \xE6\x97\xA5\xE7\x85\xA7` itself is `<type 'unicode'>`

How to decode it to the real string `山东 日照` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you printed the `repr()` output of your `unicode` string then you appear to have a [*Mojibake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), bytes data decoded using the wrong encoding.

First encode back to bytes, then decode using the right codec. This may be as simple as encoding as Latin-1:

```
unicode_string.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

This depends on how the incorrect decoding was applied however. If a Windows codepage (like CP1252) was used, you can end up with Unicode data that is not actually encodable back to CP1252 if UTF-8 bytes outside the CP1252 range were force-decoded anyway.

The best way to repair such mistakes is using the [`ftfy` library](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which knows how to deal with forced-decoded Mojibake texts for a variety of codecs.

For your small sample, Latin-1 *appears* to work just fine:

```
>>> unicode_string = u'\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE4\xB8\x9C \xE6\x97\xA5\xE7\x85\xA7'
>>> print unicode_string.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
山东 日照
>>> import ftfy
>>> print ftfy.fix_text(unicode_string)
山东 日照
```

If you have the *literal* character `\`, `x`, followed by two digits, you have another layer of encoding where the bytes where replaced by 4 characters each. You'd have to 'decode' those to actual bytes first, by asking Python to interpret the escapes with the `string_escape` codec:

```
>>> unicode_string = ur'\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE4\xB8\x9C \xE6\x97\xA5\xE7\x85\xA7'
>>> unicode_string
u'\\xE5\\xB1\\xB1\\xE4\\xB8\\x9C \\xE6\\x97\\xA5\\xE7\\x85\\xA7'
>>> print unicode_string.decode('string_escape').decode('utf8')
山东 日照
```

`'string_escape'` is a Python 2 only codec that produces a bytestring, so it is safe to decode that as UTF-8 afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, and what if I print the dict which contains the String it shows `{u'qualifier': u'name', u'timestamp': u'1462275769186', u'value': u'\\xE5\\x8E\\x9F\\xE6\\x9D\\xA5\\xE6\\x98\\xAFolivia\\xE5\\x95\\x8A', u'columnFamily': u'interActive', u'type': u'Put', u'row': u'1771897264'}
`and `print m.get('value').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` still print `\xE5\x8E\x9F...`

Comment: @armnotstrong: You don't have bytes. You have *literal* backslashes, `x` characters and hex digits. You have a different problem here. What even produces this?

Comment: @armnotstrong: updated; from your question it was not clear that you had literal text. In future, please show the `repr()` output of such a string (which is what the `dict()` representation you showed in your comment uses for each key and value)

Comment: .original data was retrieved from hbase, and it only could store ASCII String as value. and `org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter` gives me this

Comment: I'm not familiar with spark, sorry. No idea if this is a spark issue or an issue with how the data was stored in the first place.

Comment: thanks. You have gave me enough guidance. I'll work it out from here.