# Python. Convert escaped utf string to utf-string

Tags: python

Is there any built in way to do this?

```
rawstr = r"3 \u176? \u177? 0.2\u176? (2\u952?)"
#required str is 3 ° ± 0.2° (2θ).
```

something like

```
In [1] rawstr.unescape()?
Out[1]: '3° ± 0.2° 2θ'
```

The question is how to convert rawstr to 'utf-8'.

Please see my answer for more clarity.

Please answer if better option than what I am doing right now.

Comment: you could use `codecs.raw_unicode_escape_decode`. Unfortunately your raw string contains invalid unicode escapes, hence it does not work (I'm referring to `\u176?`. They should be in the form `\uXXXX`)

Comment: Alternatively, create a bytestring (use `rb` as prefix) and use `.decode('unicode-escape')`, but this again fails because `\u176?` is not a valid unicode escape.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will have to write decoder for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode string representative of utf-8 with python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035899/how-to-decode-string-representative-of-utf-8-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows and pythonnet installed

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms

def rtf_to_text(rtf_str):
    """Converts rtf to text"""

    rtf = r"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252" + '\n' + rtf_str + '\n' + '}'
    richTextBox = WinForms.RichTextBox()
    richTextBox.Rtf = rtf
    return richTextBox.Text

print(rtf_to_text(r'3 \u176? \u177? 0.2\u176? (2\u952?)'))
-->'3 ° ± 0.2° (2θ)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, there is!

For python 2:

```
print r'your string'.decode('string_escape')
```

For python 3, you need to transform it as bytes, and then use `decode`:

```
print(rb'your string'.decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Note that this doesn't work in your case, since your symbols aren't escaped properly (even if you print them using the "normal" way, it doesn't work).

---

Your string should be like this:

```
rb'3\u00B0 \u00b1 0.2\u00B0 2\u03B8'
```

Note that if you need to transform a `string` to `bytes` in python, you can use the `bytes` function.

```
my_str = r'3\u00B0 \u00b1 0.2\u00B0 2\u03B8'
my_bytes = bytes(my_str, 'utf-8')
print my_bytes.decode('string_escape') # python 2
print(my_bytes.decode('unicode_escape')) # python 3
```

Comment: I thinks it is ansi text.

Comment: "ANSI text" is not a well-defined term.  On Windows, it was misleadingly used in the past to refer to the system's local default encoding, which was widely further misinterpreted to be a particular code page (commonly 1252, though you see all of 437, 850, and whatever is the default in the reader's locale).